# Why don't we pray the Sunnah Rakaats of Salah in Jamaat (Congregation)?

Tags: salat, sunnah, jamaat, fard

Allah says in the Qu'ran:

> “When you (O Messenger Muhammad) are among them, and lead them in As‑Salaah (the prayer), let one party of them stand up [in Salaah (prayer)] with you taking their arms with them; when they finish their prostrations, let them take their positions in the rear and let the other party come up which have not yet prayed, and let them pray with you”
>
> [al-Nisa’ 4:102](https://quran.com/4/102)

In al-Saheehayn (the following version was narrated by al-Bukhaari) it is narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “By the One in Whose hand is my soul, I had thought of ordering that wood be gathered, then I would command the call to prayer to be given, and I would appoint a man to lead the people in prayer, then I would go to men [who do not attend the congregational prayer] and burn their houses down around them. By the One in Whose hand is my soul, if anyone of you had known that he would receive a bone covered with meat or two (small) pieces of meat in a sheep’s foot, he would come for 'Isha' prayer.”

This hadith and the Quranic verse state the Fard prayer should be prayed in [congregation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congregation).

When we go to pray salah at a mosque, we pray the Sunnah prayer first and then we wait for the Imam to lead us in jamaat of the Fard prayer.

**Is there any reason why we don't pray the Sunnah rakaats of prayer in jammat(congregation) like we pray the Fard rakaats in jammat(congregation)?**

Comment: Because the Prophet pbuh showed us how to pray them, beside the fact that they are optional: one may pray them or leave them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allah have mercy on him) said:

> Voluntary prayers done in congregation are of two types, one of which
>   it is Sunnah to do in congregation, such as the eclipse prayer,
>   prayers for rain, and qiyaam during Ramadaan (Taraweeh). These are
>   always done in congregation as is the Sunnah. The second type are not
>   done in congregation, such as qiyaam al-layl, the regular Sunnah
>   prayers, Duha prayer, tahiyyat al-masjid (greeting the mosque) and so
>   on. But if they are done in congregation occasionally, that is
>   permissible. As for doing them in congregation on an ongoing basis,
>   that is not prescribed, rather it is a reprehensible innovation. The
>   Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) and the Sahabaah
>   and Taabi’een were not accustomed to offering naafil prayers in
>   congregation. The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
>   only rarely offered voluntary prayers in congregation. He used to pray
>   qiyaam al-layl on his own, but when Ibn 'Abbaas stayed overnight with
>   him, he prayed with him. On another occasion, Hudhayfah prayed with
>   him, and on another occasion Ibn Mas’ood prayed with him. Similarly he
>   also prayed at the house of ‘Utbaan ibn Maalik al-Ansaari, in a place
>   that he (‘Utbaan) took as a prayer place for himself, so he prayed
>   with him, and he also led Anas and his mother and the orphan in
>   prayer, but in general his voluntary prayers were offered alone.

So there is nothing wrong in offering some naafil prayers in congregation, but this should not be a regular habit such that every regular Sunnah prayer is offered in congregation, because that is not prescribed.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any reason why we don't pray the Sunnah rakaats of prayer in congregation like we pray the Fard rakaats in congregation?

I believe you are asking about the *Sunnah Mu'akkadah* (oft-repeated Sunnah prayers).

If so, it is because neither the Prophet ﷺ not his companions set a precedent in this matter. They would pray these *Sunnah* prayers individually, and we follow the example set by them.

Answer (score -1):

We pray Sunnah prayers in congregation, it's in ramadaan time as 8 units or 20 units or 36 units.

Comment: That's a special case and it is discussed matter whether it is apropriate to do so.